# Unable to print JSON response in HTML page AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a AJAX function as below:

```
function ajx(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!


try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
       // alert(ajaxRequest.readyState);
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                    //alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);

                    var res = ajaxRequest.responseText;


                    var a = JSON.parse(res);


                    var v1 = a[0];
                    var v2 = a[1];
                    var v3 = a[2];

                    //alert(v1);

                    document.getElementById('vara').value = v1;
                    document.getElementById('varb').value = v2;
                    document.getElementById('varc').value = v3;


    }
}

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); }
```

the HTML where the `id` present are :

```
<div id="vara"></div>
<div id="varb"></div>
<div id="varc"></div>
```

And the corresponding `ajax.php` is:

```
 <?php

$resp = array('man','cow','dog');

echo json_encode($resp);

?>
```

If I alert `v1` `v2` or `v3`  it shows `man`, `cow`, and `dog` respectively. But the it is not printing the values in HTML. Whats wrong?

Comment: Show your JSON sample

Comment: `["man","cow","dog"]`

Comment: Is it `ajax.php` or `ajx.php`? You spelled it both ways throughout your question. Also, you can't **just** check for the `.readyState` being 4...you also need to check the `.status` being 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new property on your divs called value because they don't have a value property.  You want to set the innerHTML or innerText:

```
document.getElementById('vara').innerHTML = v1;
document.getElementById('varb').innerHTML = v2;
document.getElementById('varc').innerHTML = v3;
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('vara')` returns an `HTMLDivElement`, which doesn't have a `value` property.

You can check this using the construct:

```
'value' in document.getElementById('vara'); //false
```

Use the innerHTML property instead, which `HTMLDivElement` inherits from `HTMLElement`.

```
'innerHTML' in document.getElementById('vara'); //true
```

The value property is only defined for `HTMLInputElement`s (`<input type='text' />` etc. )